# Ticking a checkbox with integration testing

Tags: laravel, integration-testing, laravel-5

I have a laravel 5.2 app, and in the view I have 3 checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="11">
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="7">
```

I have a test for the page

```
$this->visit(route('staff.create'))
     ->type($name = str_random(), 'name')
     ->type($phone = str_random(), 'phone')
     ->set('roles', 5) // <--- what to do here
     ->press('Save')
     ->seePageIs(route('staff.index'))
     ->see($name);
```

Everything works expect setting the roles. The check test helper doesn't allow you to pass a value ( `$this->check($elementName)` ). I thought it would be 'set' but that fails too.

How can I check my first checkbox in the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked `InteractsWithPages` trait and I don't think it supports input arrays out of the box. You could try to replace set() with:

```
->storeInput('roles', 5);
```

or

```
->storeInput('roles', [ 5 ]);
```

And if it's not enough – you can override this method in your Test Case.